# How to catch all kinds of interrupt Requests in jSerialCom library?

Tags: java, serial-port, serial-communication, interrupt-handling, rxtx

As we all know, [jSerialCom](https://github.com/Fazecast/jSerialComm) is a high-quality Java library for reading serial data;
Previously, [RXTX](http://fizzed.com/oss/rxtx-for-java) was also a good choice,

So in jSerialCom, how to catch all kinds of interrupt events like RXTX?

In RXTX, there are these java statements to catch various interrupts event

> ```
> serialPort.notifyOnFramingError (true);
>
> serialPort.notifyOnBreakInterrupt (true);
> ```

then,in catch code,we can write:

```
switch ( event.getEventType ()) {

    case SerialPortEvent.FE :

        break;

    case SerialPortEvent.OUTPUT_ BUFFER_ EMPTY:

        break;

    case SerialPortEvent.DATA_ AVAILABLE:

        //read data of serial port ...  
        break;

    case default:

        break;
```

But what about of jSerialCom?
There is only 'LISTENING_EVENT_DATA_AVAILABLE' like blow code ? No need to catch other interrupt Requests?

```
if ( event.getEventType () != SerialPort.LISTENING_EVENT_DATA_AVAILABLE ) {

     return;

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neither the current source code nor the API documentation has such a feature.

[Fazecast/jSerialComm](https://github.com/Fazecast/jSerialComm)
[public final void waitForSerialEvent() throws Exception](https://github.com/Fazecast/jSerialComm/blob/3d4c7d7abb4b5d4abf01dde4e25d966c76f0e306/src/main/java/com/fazecast/jSerialComm/SerialPort.java#L1351)

Windows:
[JNIEXPORT jboolean JNICALL Java_com_fazecast_jSerialComm_SerialPort_configEventFlags(JNIEnv *env, jobject obj, jlong serialPortFD)](https://github.com/Fazecast/jSerialComm/blob/3d4c7d7abb4b5d4abf01dde4e25d966c76f0e306/src/main/c/Windows/SerialPort_Windows.c#L521)
[JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_com_fazecast_jSerialComm_SerialPort_waitForEvent(JNIEnv *env, jobject obj, jlong serialPortFD)](https://github.com/Fazecast/jSerialComm/blob/3d4c7d7abb4b5d4abf01dde4e25d966c76f0e306/src/main/c/Windows/SerialPort_Windows.c#L554)

Posix:
[JNIEXPORT jboolean JNICALL Java_com_fazecast_jSerialComm_SerialPort_configEventFlags(JNIEnv *env, jobject obj, jlong serialPortFD)](https://github.com/Fazecast/jSerialComm/blob/3d4c7d7abb4b5d4abf01dde4e25d966c76f0e306/src/main/c/Posix/SerialPort_Posix.c#L468)
[JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_com_fazecast_jSerialComm_SerialPort_waitForEvent(JNIEnv *env, jobject obj, jlong serialPortFD)](https://github.com/Fazecast/jSerialComm/blob/3d4c7d7abb4b5d4abf01dde4e25d966c76f0e306/src/main/c/Posix/SerialPort_Posix.c#L501)

---

Documentation:
[Home - jSerialComm](https://github.com/Fazecast/jSerialComm/wiki)
[API Documentation](http://fazecast.github.io/jSerialComm/javadoc/com/fazecast/jSerialComm/package-summary.html)
[Class SerialPortEvent](http://fazecast.github.io/jSerialComm/javadoc/com/fazecast/jSerialComm/SerialPortEvent.html)
[Class SerialPortIOException](http://fazecast.github.io/jSerialComm/javadoc/com/fazecast/jSerialComm/SerialPortIOException.html)

Comment: I also found the lack of this aspect:(. I don't think jSerialCom does a good job in documentation and promotion. The author never answers any questions from developers.